# ansible handler not found when used when included as play within pre_tasks

Tags: ansible

In my pre_task of master playbook(site.yml), 
I have included one of the playbooks from a my_role 
(located in my_role/tasks/my_playbook)

This my_playbook calls a handler, which is located in the role directory(my_role/handlers/main.yml)
and I am getting handler not found error.

What are the types I can use inside the pre_task??

Comment: Can you edit your question to post relevant snippets of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlers defined inside `my_role` are for use by that role only.

If you include some tasks from your role like `my_role/tasks/tasklist1.yml` inside `pre_tasks` block of your master playbook and expect it to use some handlers also defined inside that role, you should also include its handlers as separate statement, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  pre_tasks:
    - include: roles/role1/tasks/main.yml
  handlers:
    - include: roles/role1/handlers/main.yml
```